# 'some respect for myself': What does it mean?

Tags: quantifiers, comparative-degree

I have recently heard of the sentence 'I have some respect for myself'. What is the difference between this sentence and another one 'I respect myself'? Is it a matter of degree of respect? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What leads you to doubt the meaning?

Comment: If you have only 'some' respect for something, you may not give it your entire respect.

Comment: It might be said by someone who is ashamed of something they did, but is trying to [salve their conscience](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/salve-your-conscience).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "respect" is a noun in "*I have some respect for myself*," and a verb in "*I respect myself*." Many "feeling"-words work that way: "I feel love for him"; "I have no forgiveness for her"; "I have the deepest admiration for you."

If we leave out the word "some", there is little difference between "I respect myself" and "I have respect for myself."

Once we add "some," the meaning becomes dependent on context. It's not clear, unless you provide context, whether the point is that I have *some* respect, rather than *none*, or whether I *only* have *some*, rather than complete respect. The sentence "I respect myself" does not make any suggestion of degrees of respect.

Comment: So the degree of respect is uncertain with the sentence 'I have some respect for myself'. It depends on the context. I am clear now. Thanks.